# Laravel 7 issue with redirect after first-time login on chrome

Tags: php, laravel

There is an issue with Laravel redirecting to dashboard (or any other page) after attempting to login for the first time after starting the Google Chrome Browser.
Everyone seems to be having this issue, and we're yet to either find a fix, or the root cause of the problem.

There is no error message, page just keeps loading till infinity.
if I reload the login page, I discover that the user has actually been authenticated and I get redirected to the correct page.

I'm running my site on XAMPP with PHP 7.3.11

Anyone found a fix?

here's my LoginController code, I only added the `redirectTo()` method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function redirectTo()
    {
        if (session('url.intended')) {
            return redirect(session('url.intended'));
        }

        return route('dashboard.index');
    }
}
```

Here's my route:

```
web.php:


<?php

Auth::routes([
    'verify'=> true
]);
Route::name('dashboard.')->prefix('dashboard')->middleware(['auth', 'checkMeta', 'verified', 'checkActive'])->group(function ()
{
  Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('index');
}
```

Then on `Dashboardcontroller.php`, I have this:

```
<?php

use...

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
   public function index(){
     return view('dashboard');
   }
}
```

Comment: Show the routes code

Comment: thanks @MariosNikolaou kindly check, I've updated my question to reflect all those info.

Comment: Do you have folder Dashboard (in resources->views) and inside the folder index view?

Comment: i think you have mistake in function index change -> View('dashboard.index')

Comment: @MariosNikolaou all those are working fine. the logic in my dashboard controller is quite complex, just decided to share this to kinda give you an idea. The problem is not actually in returning the view, the site works absolutely fine, except i'm logging-in for the first time after starting google chrome. Every other browser seem not to have this problem. Could it be an issue with chrome?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: **There is an issue with Laravel redirecting to dashboard (or any other page) after attempting to login for the first time after starting the Google Chrome Browser**

Comment: You can do it manually, create auth controller and use Auth::attempt()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Chrome only. I had the same issue. Update Chrome to version 85.0.4183.83 and it should work.

Here you can get more information: [Laravel got stuck after login.](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-got-stuck-after-login-laravel-58)

And as a fallback function i add small vanilla javascript in login.blade.php, that redirects me after 5 sec. Because you are actually logged in, but the redirection stuck...

```
var form = document.querySelector('.login-form');

form.addEventListener("submit", function(evt) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.replace("/home");
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of research about this subject and test anyway but I didn't get any good result, but I understood This problem can be caused by confusing the names of the sessions by chrome or any browser, so I changed the session name in `config/session.php` by adding a random string to cookie my problem resolved.

my old code

```
'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),
```

my new code

```
'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_newsession'
    ),
```